# C#/WPF: Bind ComboBox to two Elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I've following objects

```
public int PersonAge { get; set; }
public List<PersonGroup> PersonList { get; set; }

public class PersonGroup()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DefaultAge { get; set; }
}
```

My ComboBox is bound to PersonList, while I also have a TextBox which is bound to PersonAge.
If a user enters the number '20' into the TextBox (PersonAge), I want to select the according PersonGroup in the ComboBox, and if a User selects the PersonGroup-Item "Test1" from the ComboBox, I want the TextBox to display 10 in the TextBox (because PersonList[1] would be for example Name = "Test1"; DefaultAge = 10;)

Any ideas how to solve this via DataBinding?

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,
Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could try using the SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath properties on ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" SelectedValuePath="DefaultAge" SelectedValue="{Binding PersonAge}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

edit1: i think the textbox can bind to PersonAge instead, makes for cleaner code imo....not sure, unfortunately i cant test it at the moment.

Comment: Concerning edit1: Yes, that works even better and provides less code :-) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can expose [ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx), instead of raw List. Set up [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.filter.aspx) function. And whenether PersonAge is updated you call [Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh.aspx) method from your view. As for another part - you can always bind to current item in the collection view. E.g.:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PersonList/DefaultAge}"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with ListCollectionView. Bubblewrap's solution is more easy to implement in the current solution, but I'm sure yours will help me a lot for the next tasks :-) Cheers